# What does 'to ditch in droves' mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-meaning

Could anybody please tell me the meaning of a phrase *to ditch in droves*? Is it an idiom?

> Performance reviews are pointless, insulting and culture-killing programs that smart companies are ditching in droves.

From this sentence my guess is *to throw away* or *to get rid of*.

Comment: Did you look up *droves* in a dictionary? Mine defines it as: *a large number of people or things doing or undergoing the same thing*. It should be logical then that it means "the smart companies are abandoning performance reviews".

Comment: Thanks. What I've found was 'crowd'. I'm asking because I wouldn't use 'abandoning in crowd'.

Comment: "Droves" does not describe *where* the reviews are being "ditched", but rather *how many*.  You might understand it better as "Droves of smart companies are ditching performance reviews".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[definition of droves at Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.wattpad.com/forums/discussion/1162176/Show+or+Tell%3F)

[definition of ditch at Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ditch)

"Ditch in droves" is not an idiom, but "droves" which originally referred to herded animals can refer to a group of people all doing the same thing.

So, "ditching in droves" in that sentence means the smart companies were abandoning the performance reviews. Ditch, being used in a verb sense of to get rid of.

Comment: Yes. It is one of those words which is nowadays only used in a metaphorical sense. I am curious though, why you say "ditching in droves" is "not an idiom". It seems to satisfy the  [definition of an idiom](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=wD2zWLr0L6isgAb95oywBQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=idiom+definition&*) to me.

Comment: I thought the question was whether the group of words together "ditching in droves" was an idiom. The idiom is more commonly "flocking in droves".

Comment: @WS2 - As you well know, "ditching in droves" is not an "idiom", in the usual sense, because it's neither a common expression, nor does it have a meaning that cannot be derived from the meanings of the component words.  It is "idiomatic" use of the language, but that doesn't make it "an idiom".

Comment: @KaranSeraph I do not recall ever hearing "flocking in droves", but it is certainly a possibility , as are doing many other things in droves, e.g. "leaving", "assembling", "voting", "relocating", "turning up", "refusing" etc.

Comment: @HotLicks Well I shan't split hairs with you as to whether it is an "idiom", or whether it is merely "idiomatic use of language". But I would certainly have considered it idiomatic. The normal sense of "ditching" is about crashing in a ditch e.g at the side of a road. And "droves" usually involve animals. So I suggest "ditching in droves" has a meaning "that cannot be derived from the meanings of the component words".

Comment: @WS2 - Actually, when I hear "ditching" I think of an airplane making an emergency landing in water, as with the [Jan 2009 Sullenberger event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Airways_Flight_1549).

Comment: @HotLicks Which itself is idiomatic. I'm fairly sure the term originates from carriages on the highway going awry and ending up in the ditch (the narrow trench parallel with roads to take the water which drained off them). The OP's idiom derives from OED sense 6c of the verb is * transf. and fig. To defeat, frustrate; to abandon, discard; to jilt. (See also quot. 1899.) slang (orig. U.S.).* The aeroplane landing in water is sense 6b.

Comment: @WS2 - Yeah, I agree that "ditch" is used as an idiom/metaphor here, as is "droves".  But "ditching in droves" is not an idiom, but a simple combination of words.